# How compatible is float:none?

Tags: css, css-float, compatibility

I am a little confused about the compatibility and useage of Float:none;.
Basicaly I am using float:left in my general stylesheet and want to create an exception to this using a media query. In this query I want to 'undo' the float left.

My first thought was to use 'Float:none;' however I seem to find very little documentation on how this should be used and if it's compatible with all browsers.

I checked 'caniuse.com' and it gave me two different answers to the same question... When I search for '[float](http://caniuse.com/#search=float)' it says it's barely supported. And when I search for '[Float:none;](http://caniuse.com/#search=float%3Anone%3B)' it says it's widely supported.

Should I be using float:none for this cause and/or is there a better way to 'undo' a float?

Comment: the first float you searched is about  javascript typed arrays as clearly stated in the description. Nothing to share with the css property... `float: none` works fine

Comment: As stated from already 3 answers, `float: none` is supported (as long as CSS is activated and your file loaded :) ). Media Queries are "only" supported by IE9+ which should be really fine except in very corporate environment where IE8+ would still be supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float: none;` should be fine to "undo" a floating environment. As an alternative, you can also set `clear: both;` on an element, that ends the floating environment.

Or in your case: `clear: left;`

In general, float (with all its properties) is [widely supported](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp) by browsers. Make sure you looked at the CSS property when checking "caniuse":

> CSS 2.1 properties (well-supported subset): float (none | left |
>   right)

Answer (score 3):

Float:none is supported in all browsers.

Look for "CSS 2.1 Properties" here: http://caniuse.com/#search=float

Answer (score 2):

float: none has been fully compatible aross all browsers for many years. If it isn't working for you then check the specificity of your selectors. The first link you point to isn't actually about the float property.